# algorithm for filling boxes/parcels

Tags: algorithm

i need to fill boxes in an optimal way.
the products that should be placed in the boxes have a weight and an info how many items of the product could be placed in a box.

```
prod1 : weight 9 kilogramm and info 5 (5 of prod1 could be placed in a box)
prod2 : weight 8 kilogramm and info 4 (4 of prod2 could be placed in a box)
prod3 : weight 7,5 kilogramm and info 6 (6 of prod3 could be placed in a box)
prod4 : weight 7,5 kilogramm and info 3 (3 of prod4 could be placed in a box)
prod5 : weight 27 kilogramm and info 2 (2 of prod5 could be placed in a box )
```

Now i have to write a algorithm to fill the boxes in its best way.
For example:
Cust orders 7 * prod1 and 1 prod3
My pgm should make 2 boxes.

```
1 contains 5 * prod1
1 contains 2 * prod1 and 1* prod1
```

My brain knows that but i dont know how to code it.
i have to start with the biggest products - the products that have the smallest count of items per box.
But if i have space in the box i have to look for other - smaller products that could be placed in the box.

i hope, somebody understands my description.

bye

Comment: What is exactly "the best way" of filling the box? Is it the least amount of empty space in all boxes except the last one? Or equal empty space in all boxes? What is the box size?

Comment: it should be the least amount of empty space in all boxes except the last one - the boxes size should be not relevant but the max-weight ist 50 Kilogramms

Comment: This is a Bin Packing Problem with additional constraint of maximum number of products of a particular type per bin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic knapsack problem. I don't think that would be an asnwer to paste here the corresponding algorithms, which have been developed by others. So look here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem, you will find exaclty what you want.

Comment: Not exactly a knapsack problem. It is more of a Bin Packing Problem in my opinion.